# How can I set the background-image to a paperclip attachment url?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, paperclip, background-image, attachment

I'm having trouble getting the paperclip attachment URL to style a background image. The following is in my view:

```
  <% @auction.lots.each do |lot| %>
    <div class="lot-with-image" style="background-image: url('#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{lot.image}'); width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 5px solid black"></div>
  <% end %>
```

This is the html:

```
<div class="lot-with-image" style="background-image: url('#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{lot.image}'); width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 5px solid black">
```

I also tried `#{lot.image.url}` as well, but I got pretty much the same result.

If there is a better way to use paperclip to style the background-image, I'm very open to suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<% @auction.lots.each do |lot| %>
    <div class="lot-with-image" style="background-image: url('<%= lot.image.url %>'); width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 5px solid black"></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That got me the error: `no implicit conversion of Paperclip::Attachment into String`

Comment: please pass lot.image.url  instead of lot.image

Comment: BTW paperclip url should give full path of image,, I don't think u need request.protocol,  request.host_with_port. Just <%= lot.image.url %> should work

Comment: Thanks that worked very well but I just changed the quotes around `'<%= lot.image.url %>'` to be single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Please to change into:

```
<% @auction.lots.each do |lot| %>
    <div class="lot-with-image" style="background-image: url("<%= lot.image.url %>"); width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 5px solid black"></div>
<% end %>
```

This is the brief summary [Show image in view](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#show-view)